A Limited Advertising Test on this Site
For some time, we’ve been exploring the concept of using open auction to manage a small amount of advertising on some Stack Exchange sites.  Under this model, advertisers (who have been organized into categories based on their products) “bid” for an advertising spot. There is a floor price - a minimum price for the spot, and all bids must exceed that floor price. We do not use the open auction model on this site, which has been largely devoid of advertising (although the site has been eligible for advertising, not many ads have been placed here).
Objective
For this experiment we wanted to test on one site that we can closely monitor and Mathematics is a site that advertisers have expressed interest in outside of the technology Stack Exchange sites. In this experiment, 1% of the theoretical advertising inventory on the Mathematics site will be available for open auction, with strict controls in place. This initiative aims to help us better understand potential new revenue opportunities and possibly refine our ad sales approach in the future while delivering relevant ads to users of this site.
Experiment Details

Experiment Launch Date/Time: October 1, 2024
Experiment End Date/Time: The campaign will tentatively run until November 30, 2024. After this period, we will evaluate the results and decide whether to conclude the test or keep it running. The experiment could be paused or concluded early if major issues arise.

Strict Controls
We have an extensively vetted block list to prevent bids that are not relevant to users of our network and for this site. If we notice bids from advertisers that are technically allowed but may not be the best fit for the site, we can add those advertisers to the block list. These blocks will allow us to keep the ads relevant for this site. The ads from relevant advertisers could include:

Books
Laptops
Smartphones & Tablets
Tutoring Services
Online courses

Our Creative Guidelines have not changed. If you see an ad that you feel doesn't fit on the site, please report it by clicking the “Report this ad” button underneath the ad.
What will this look like?
You may see the advertisements appear in a number of familiar placements on the page, which include the right sidebar, top leaderboard, and mid-page leaderboard; the ads will not cover any content.  We hope that the ads that show up will be useful and relevant to the community here.  There should not be any offensive or sensitive ads, as the filters should block them from being approved. If you notice that particular ads are less relevant or violate our advertising standards, we encourage you to report them.

Why are you doing this?
We are conducting this experiment to learn more about potential revenue opportunities in our ad approach. By opening up 1% of the ad space to auction, we can determine if this approach makes sense for this site. This approach allows us to gain valuable insights without disrupting the day-to-day experience of using the site.
We appreciate your understanding as we work to modernize our advertising experience.

Welcome to Math Meta. I suggest adding the [tag:featured] tag to this question. Also, apart from "... that the ads that show up will be useful and relevant to the community here", are you aware of any plans, even if currently only fairly tentative, for the extra revenue from the ads (if not these ones, then maybe if you expand the # of ads) to be used to help make this site, and other similar sites, better? I'm thinking of things such as investigating either upgrading the version of MathJax being used, or switching to another math typesetting library (e.g., KaTeX).

"We appreciate your understanding as we work to modernize our advertising experience." Sure. And let's work to modernize our Covid "experience", and our food poisoning "experience", and our car crash "experience", and and and ....

I would suggest not advertising tutoring services here, since some advertisers masquerade as tutoring while actually being cheating services. This would go against part of the ethos here, which is against homework answers and cheating.

@user400188 That is certainly a valid concern: we have a floor price that we believe will weed out those types of advertisers, who typically bid well below that threshold, and we will also monitor what comes through. In the case that we are wrong and you see such bad actors are still able to break through please report the ad. We are not opposed to the idea of blocking off the subcategory.

The encroachment of ads on Stackexchange - first "a small amount" to test the waters, and later more if there's not enough pushback - is a great example of Cory Doctorow's theory of "enshittification", or platform decay.  First platforms create high-quality offerings to attract users, then they degrade those offerings to maximize profits for shareholders.     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enshittification

@JohnBaez There's nothing complicated about Stack Exchange that can't be replicated by open source tools. There already exist sites like Codidact but they haven't attracted a sufficient community to grow. (Also hi John Baez)

For anybody interested, re: my initial comment above, just only about an hour ago, staff member balpha posted on the network Meta site this answer which starts with "In preparation for a MathJax upgrade, ..." In the comments below, Emil Jeřábek asked for details, e.g., about upgrading to "MathJax to v3 (or even v4)", with balpha replying with "I'm not involved in any of that, so I don't know the detailed plans".

Re MathJax, look for an announcement today, but basically, we've done the work to upgrade to the latest stable release (3.2.2, from memory?) and gotten a lot of the work for v4 ready to go. We're going to introduce 3.x as a beta, with an eye toward a fast follow release sometime next quarter to 4. It's going to be a profile setting, I believe.

This is a storm in a teacup. Stackoverflow had Google Adsense advertising in 2009/2010. Joel Spolsky then removed it not because people disliked it, but because it wasn't making enough money. Later Spolsky opened a job site for programmers which is advertised on Stackoverflow. I don't see any reason at all to object to advertising on the maths site, also don't understand how people expect the site to be run if it doesn't bring in any income.

@SuzuHirose I think the criticism you see on such posts is arguably part of a bigger picture. As you know in recent years, the SE has been riddled with bad decisions and poor crisis management that left a strong negative impression for many of the users. That the evil capitalism has consumed the spirit of the site and now the only objective of its keepers is to "make more money" and "we only care about our shareholders". So it is no surprise that such posts are nuked with downvotes even if they sound reasonable out of context.

There have been various forms of advertising on various parts of the network for years. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20%5badvertising%5d%20-%5blegacy-stack-overflow-jobs%5d&searchOn=3 Members with a modest amount of rep have the option of reducing their ad exposure.

@polfosol yes I am aware of the general atmosphere so I thought a long time before contributing my opinion, but I'll stick with it. I think what Elon Musk did with Twitter, with allowing user subscriptions and then sharing the advertising revenue with subscribed users, might be a useful way to reward contributors to the site as well as bring in some money to keep the system running. (Cue inevitable complaints about Musk from the usual bores.)

"We hope that the ads that show up will be useful and relevant to the community here." There is no such thing as a useful or relevant ad. Putting ads on MSE is a decision that is maximally hateful towards the user base.

Does this have anything to do with the "20,000+ Worksheets" stuff currently polluting pages on mathstack?

Privacy implications
What are the privacy implications of this approach? Will more information on the person in front of the screen (e.g., username, profile, question/answer history, favored tag...) be collected and shared with Google and the companies interested in the bidding?
Is there a difference for users that have opted out of targeted ads and cookies?
Does this sharing of information follows the rules that are stated in your privacy policy?

This is partially answered in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404116/.
